# Typeproviders, websharper, f#, builiding order

Tags: build, f#, type-providers, websharper

So I have added some data using typeproviders into my applications ([github link](https://github.com/whole/bork/tree/master/Website1))
So here is the problem.

1) What I wanted is that my `Site.fs` use data and build div according to rules I gave it. Everything looks fine except....

I put back end calculation into WebSite project and probably because Web is startup project calculations in WebSite are never done and never pushed on database.
It is only displayed data which is already in database.

Plus sometimes there is only `${title}` and body instead of text provided in fsharp (even using default sitelet sample site). Is that normal? Restarting visual studio helps.

P.S.: sorry if my code doesn't look so spectacular I want it to work first and after that I will refactor it.

Comment: I know you've got an answer now, but it would be good for future visitors if you could include a minimal sample of the problem code directly here. (Taking account of link rot and the fact that I suspect you will now update your code at github).

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, top-level values (such as your `Site.items`) are computed once at the launch of the application. If you want it to be computed at every page load, it needs to be computed inside the function that receives a `Context<Action>`. [1]

For example, you can do something like the following:

```
let getItems() =
    seq {
        for i in borkData.parseData.db.ONEPOST do
            yield [i.Title; i.Link; i.Poslodavac; i.MjestoRada; i.RokZaPrijavu]
    }

let JobsPage =
    Skin.WithTemplate "Jobs" <| fun ctx -> // this is the function that gets called for every page
        let items = getItems()
        [
            for i in items ->
                Div [Class "job"] -<
                  [
                    A [Class "title"] -< [HRef i.[1]] -< [ Text i.[0]]
                    P [Class "posted top"]  -< [ Text i.[3] ]
                    P [Class "employer"]  -< [ Text i.[2] ]
                  ]
        ]
```

Here, since `getItems` is a function, it computes its return value every time you ask for it with `let items = getItems()`.

---

[1] You could also do it inside the function passed to `Sitelet.Infer`, if you used it. This would be useful if the `Content` you want to return depends on `items`, for example if you wanted to use a different template depending on `items`.

Comment: I figured out (silly me it was easy) and big tnx for taking time to take a look at my code and find error.